# Mac mini (Late 2014) second monitor

Tags: thunderbolt

I have a Mac mini (Late 2014). I want to connect a second monitor to it. I have a monitor connected to the HDMI port. The Mac mini has two Thunderbolt 2 ports and the second monitor that I want to use only supports DVI and VGA. My question is, do I need a special Thunderbolt 2 to DVI/VGA adapter or can I use a Mini Display to DVI/VGA adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thunderbolt 2 ports on Macs support mini-DisplayPort natively, so you can absolutely use an mDP-DVI/VGA adapter.